# Struggling to upgrade to WebPack 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

I am attempting to migrate to Webpack 2 from 1 and am receiving quite a few errors. I managed to get rid of some errors but am still receiving the following:

$ node scripts/start.js 
(node:42015) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): WebpackOptionsValidationError: Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.

- configuration.resolve has an unknown property 'fallback'. These properties are valid:
  object { alias?, aliasFields?, cachePredicate?, descriptionFiles?, enforceExtension?, enforceModuleExtension?, extensions?, fileSystem?, mainFields?, mainFiles?, moduleExtensions?, modules?, plugins?, resolver?, symlinks?, unsafeCache?, useSyncFileSystemCalls? }
  (node:42015)

DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

My webpack config is below

```
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
var ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
var InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
var url = require('url');
var paths = require('./paths');
var getClientEnvironment = require('./env');


function ensureSlash(path, needsSlash) {
    var hasSlash = path.endsWith('/');
    if (hasSlash && !needsSlash) {
        return path.substr(path, path.length - 1);
    } else if (!hasSlash && needsSlash) {
        return path + '/';
    } else {
        return path;
    }
}


// like /todos/42/static/js/bundle.7289d.js. We have to know the root.
var homepagePath = require(paths.appPackageJson).homepage;
var homepagePathname = homepagePath ? url.parse(homepagePath).pathname : 

%PUBLIC_PATH%xyz.
var publicUrl = ensureSlash(homepagePathname, false);

var env = getClientEnvironment(publicUrl);

// Assert this just to be safe.
// Development builds of React are slow and not intended for production.
if (env['process.env'].NODE_ENV !== '"production"') {
    throw new Error('Production builds must have NODE_ENV=production.');
}

module.exports = {

    bail: true,

    entry: [
        require.resolve('./polyfills'),
        paths.appIndexJs
    ],
    output: {
        // The build folder.
        path: paths.appBuild,
        // Generated JS file names (with nested folders).
        // There will be one main bundle, and one file per asynchronous chunk.
        // We don't currently advertise code splitting but Webpack supports it.
        filename: 'assets/static/js/[name].js',
        chunkFilename: 'assets/static/js/[name].chunk.js',
        // We inferred the "public path" (such as / or /my-project) from homepage.
        publicPath: publicPath
    },
    resolve: {

       extensions: ['.js', '.json', '.jsx'],
        alias: {
            // Support React Native Web
            // https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/08/a-glimpse-into-the-future-with-react-native-for-web/
            'react-native': 'react-native-web'
        }
    },

    module: {

        rules: [

            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                loader: 'eslint',
                include: paths.appSrc,
                enforce: 'pre'
            },
            {
                exclude: [
                    /\.html$/,
                    /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    /\.css$/,
                    /\.json$/,
                    /\.svg$/
                ],
                loader: 'url',
                options: {
                    limit: 10000,
                    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                }
            },
            // Process JS with Babel.
            {
                test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                include: paths.appSrc,
                loader: 'babel',

            },

            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?importLoaders=1!postcss')
                // Note: this won't work without `new ExtractTextPlugin()` in `plugins`.
            },
            // JSON is not enabled by default in Webpack but both Node and Browserify
            // allow it implicitly so we also enable it.
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: 'json'
            },
            // "file" loader for svg
            {
                test: /\.svg$/,
                loader: 'file',
                options: {
                    name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },


    plugins: [
        // Makes the public URL available as %PUBLIC_URL% in index.html, e.g.:
        // <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
        // In production, it will be an empty string unless you specify "homepage"
        // in `package.json`, in which case it will be the pathname of that URL.
        new InterpolateHtmlPlugin({
            PUBLIC_URL: publicUrl
        }),
        // Generates an `index.html` file with the <script> injected.
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            inject: true,
            template: paths.appHtml,
            minify: {
                removeComments: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                useShortDoctype: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                keepClosingSlash: true,
                minifyJS: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
                minifyURLs: true
            }
        }),
        // Makes some environment variables available to the JS code, for example:
        // if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') { ... }. See `./env.js`.
        // It is absolutely essential that NODE_ENV was set to production here.
        // Otherwise React will be compiled in the very slow development mode.
        new webpack.DefinePlugin(env),
        // This helps ensure the builds are consistent if source hasn't changed:
        new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
        // Try to dedupe duplicated modules, if any:
        new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
        // Minify the code.
        new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            compress: {
                screw_ie8: true, // React doesn't support IE8
                warnings: false
            },
            mangle: {
                screw_ie8: true
            },
            output: {
                comments: false,
                screw_ie8: true
            }
        }),
        // Note: this won't work without ExtractTextPlugin.extract(..) in `loaders`.
        new ExtractTextPlugin('assets/static/css/[name].css'),
        // Generate a manifest file which contains a mapping of all asset filenames
        // to their corresponding output file so that tools can pick it up without
        // having to parse `index.html`.
        new ManifestPlugin({
            fileName: 'asset-manifest.json'
        })
    ],
    // Some libraries import Node modules but don't use them in the browser.
    // Tell Webpack to provide empty mocks for them so importing them works.
    node: {
        fs: 'empty',
        net: 'empty',
        tls: 'empty'
    }
};
```

And my start.js is here https://pastebin.com/ENRYKUgL

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Right. so, somewhere in your code, you have a promise with no error handling. Additionally, some property of some object has some property that you didn't define said object to contain. The error messages aren't that cryptic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fallback` is an option of `ExtractTextPlugin`, perhaps try to define with the new `use: { //.. }` notation rather than query string notation. This may not be perfect but should get you started...

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
    fallback: 'style-loader',
    use: [
      { loader: 'css-loader', options: {importLoaders: 1}},
      { loader: 'postcss-loader' }
    ]
  })
}
```

On a side note, you shouldn't need OccurrenceOrderPlugin or DedupePlugin in Webpack 2 as they are included by default